# Image category attribute - Image is not saving in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created an image category attribute in admin panel.And i found there is an magento default bug in internet.it said need to overwrite module-catalog core files..I used di.xml to edit core files but it doesn't response...

Anyone knows alternative way to edit core files?

Comment: You can use Plugin concept for same.

Comment: i'm new to magento ...can u pls explain how to use plugin?

Comment: How to create plugin for these core files? https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Magento 2.1.8. That issue is resolved in this release along with many issues or bugs.

You can read release notes here.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8CE.html